# jpa hibernate map latest object in joincolumn object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have student and activities table.

i want to have latest activity in in Student Entity, can some one help how do i do it ?

```
    Student
    -------
    id
    name
    latest_activity_id

    student_ctivities
    --------
    id,
    name
    insertDate

    @Entity
    public class Student{

    String id;
    String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "latest_activity_id")
    // how do map latest activity (sort by insert date) to following object
    StudentActivity activity;


    }

@Entity
public class StudentActivity{
Integer id;
String name;
LocalDate insertDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to have two relations between student and StudentActivity. One being one-to-many (Student has many StudentActtivitys) and another to map the latest student (one-to-one)

So in Student have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
private Set<StudentActivity> activitys = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_current_activity", referencedColumnName = "id")
private StudentActivity currentActivity;
```

And on StudentActivity (if you want student to be visible on StudentActivity)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_Student", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Student student;
```

This is the way I usually go, it does create one more relation but it solves the problem. I guess you can also use an ordered collection or every time you need to get the latest activity have an SQL query returning based on latest item. You would also need to create one more column/attribute in StudentActivity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: student_activity table does not have student id. so StudentActivity relation in your example not gona work.

Comment: If the relationship is student has many student_activities, then student_activities is the weak part of the relationship and must have the student's ID. But in JPA, you can have the java attribute while not having the foreing key, since it knows the relationship and will attribute accordingly.